# Array.Clone() (Copy or not?)

Tags: c#, arrays, clone

I suspect that I am simply misunderstanding the Clone() method of the Array class.
However it reads "Creates a Shallow Copy of the System.Array" so I would have assumed this meant new object pointers, not the same object pointers...

Is the following really supposed to happen?

Assuming a test object...

```
public class testObject 
{
    public int propInt { get; set; }
}
```

and the following test...

```
//create a the list
List<testObject> testList = new List<testObject>();

//add items to the list
testObject item1 = new testObject();
item1.propInt = 1;
testList.Add(item1);

testObject item2 = new testObject();
item2.propInt = 2;
testList.Add(item2);

//create what should be a COPY of the array
testObject[] testArray;
testArray = (testObject[])testList.ToArray().Clone();


foreach (testObject item in testArray)
{
    item.propInt++;
}

//check items in list
foreach (testObject item in testList)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("List:" + item.propInt);
}

//check items in coppied array
foreach (testObject item in testArray)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Array:" + item.propInt);
}
```

I would expect the outcome to have been...

```
List:1
List:2

Array:2
Array:3
```

Because I assumed when I made a clone, the references in that clone would have been to a new instance of the same object type bearing the same properties as when the clone was made. Furthermore I would have assumed after modifying them, that the original list would have been untouched.

No joy, the output of this test is actually...

```
List:2
List:3

Array:2
Array:3
```

So my actions on the Clone appear to be reflected in the source of the clone as well, which to me means it did not copy the object it copied the pointer to the object, and defeated the purpose of the clone method to begin with..??

Comment: That's the exact opposite of **shallow**.  All that gets copied is the array itself

Comment: shallow copy means it is copying the pointers not creating new objects.

Comment: Ok, I can accept that, the MSDN states "A shallow copy of an Array copies only the elements of the Array, whether they are reference types or value types, but it does not copy the objects that the references refer to. The references in the new Array point to the same objects that the references in the original Array point to." which seems to support that as well. So how would I get the copy NOT referencing the original?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Shallow Copy* means you get new array, but values in an array are copied as they are. For reference types (as your class) it means the references are copied, so your new array points to the same instances of your class.

If you'd like to perform deep copy, you have to either do it yourself:

```
var copy = source.Select(x => new testObject() { propInt = x.propInt }).ToArray();
```

or use cloning library (e.g. [CloneExtensions](https://cloneextensions.codeplex.com/)).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, and even though I know this had to happen on some level for it to have worked, I would have thought it would have been in the original design of the array class.

Answer (score 1):

The Clone() method serves only the purpose to copy the Array object, not the references within it. If you want the objects to be copied, you would have to create a subclass to your desired Collection and override the Clone() method. However, the Clone() method usually derives from the ICloneable interface. You would have to check for the contained objects if the implement that Interface. I would suggest something like that :

```
public class ClonableList<T> : List<T>, ICloneable
    where T : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        ClonableList<T> newList = new ClonableList<T>();

        foreach (T item in this)
        {
            newList.Add((T)item.Clone());
        }

        return newList;
    }
}
```